# why the parameters of a submit_tag can be lost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following button and I do not understand `cause the value of the parameter that I want to send is lost

```
<%= submit_tag("NOW!", :name=>'fast', :class => 'add-basket-now', :style => "width: 160px;") %>
```

the rest of the parameters are sent but there I change the default value 'commit' to 'fast' and this is lost and not sent

when I click these are the parameters that are sent

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"GX1A5JKigE7paD0SQikdTNTzHQvI/r7JUMx+0NOmFbQ=", "quantity"=>"1", "product_id"=>"1101", "size"=>"3769", "method"=>"get"}

As you can see, no commit or fast parameters are sent, or anything that has to do with the submit_tag.

the controller is very spaghetti but the only place where I should control that parameter would be the following

```
if params[:fast] != nil 
  redirect_to checkout_path
```

Comment: As you can see the `submit_tag` method definition https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/submit_tag#dyn_source

Comment: The first parameter should be `value` and the rest is optional `hash`

Comment: @AjayBarot - Isn't that what there is there in the code? "NOW!" is the value

Comment: Could you show what your params look like when you receive the form? How do you handle params in the controller?

Comment: @BroiSatse: I thought OP is confused about the `value` and `name` parameters of `submit_tag`. Indeed we would like to see the form as well as controller code for further help.

Comment: @cisco - Ok, that seems quite interesting. Could you 1) check the rendered submit input has a correct name and value attributes 2) inspect raw request body with` request.raw_post`? Also, it seems you are submitting the form witha  get action, is this correct?